# How to set value to const in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 const CreateNewTab = () => {
      const priceMap = {};
      retrun(
          <Form>
                 <Form.Item
                  label="Price Map"
                  name="priceMap"
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input Prices!"}]}>
                             
                              {selectedProducts.flatMap(productId => products
                                  .filter(product => product.id === productId)
                                  .map(product => (
                                      <Input.Group compact>
                                          <Form.Item label={product.productName + " : "} />   
                                          {product.priceList.map((priceObj) => (
                                              <Form.Item
                                                  label={priceObj.type}
                                                  key={priceObj.priceId}>
                                                  <Input defaultValue={priceObj.price}
                                                      rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input price!" }]}
                                                      onChange={(changedValues) => { priceMap[priceObj.id] = changedValues[Object.keys(changedValues)[0]]; console.log(priceMap) }} />
                                                  </Form.Item>
                                             
                                          ))}
                                      </Input.Group>

                                  ))
                             )}
                                 
                </Form.Item>
           </Form>
)
```

I want to track the priceMap for example

```
 "priceMap": {
                "3": 2,
                "4": 5,
                "10": 2,
                "11": 5,
                "12": 2,
                "13": 5
            }
```

However, the error says Assignment to constant variable.

I have tried const [priceMap, setpriceMap] = useState([]); but it only sets single value to priceMap.
 Instead, I want to create priceMap as key value json object.

Comment: If you need to reassign a variable, use `let` instead of `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is definitely the right thing to do. That is the React hooks way of having data that, when it changes, causes a re-render.

> I have tried const [priceMap, setpriceMap] = useState([]); but it only sets single value to priceMap.

Why are you setting `priceMap` to an `Array` when you want it to be an `Object`? Try something like this:

```
const CreateNewTab = () => {
  const [priceMap, setPriceMap] = useState({});
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item
        label="Price Map"
        name="priceMap"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input Prices!"}]}
      >
        {selectedProducts.flatMap(productId => products
          .filter(product => product.id === productId)
          .map(product => (
            <Input.Group compact>
              <Form.Item label={product.productName + " : "} />   
              {product.priceList.map((priceObj) => (
                <Form.Item
                  label={priceObj.type}
                  key={priceObj.priceId}
                >
                  <Input
                    defaultValue={priceObj.price}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input price!" }]}
                    onChange={(changedValues) => {
                      setPriceMap({
                        ...priceMap,
                        [priceObj.id]: changedValues[Object.keys(changedValues)[0]]
                      })
                    }} />
                </Form.Item>
              ))}
            </Input.Group>
          ))
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Notice that when you call `setPriceMap` you pass a new object rather than mutating the object.

Comment: This answer is consistent with React best practices. State changes are handled with respective state handlers, i.e., for hooks setPriceMap (see above) or setState for class component, and a new reference should be passed for non-primitives rather than direct mutation, as in this answer.

Comment: It is partyly but never create a function in the onclick as above otherwise it degrades performance. Put it outside. onclick={mymethod}

Comment: @Jacob What's the diffence between priceMap and  ...priceMap?

Comment: `...priceMap` is copying the properties of `priceMap` into the new object literal being passed into `setPriceMap`. It's called object spreading. Basically what's being done is we're making a shallow copy of `priceMap`, overwriting the property `priceObj.id` with a new value, and setting the result as the new value for `priceMap` on the next render.

Answer (score 0):

A constant is exactly what the name suggests. It will always be constant and immutable. If you change it to `let priceMap = {};` you should be able to change its values

Comment: You'd be able to change its value, but that's not the way to author a React component. On its next render, the value will be wiped out.